# Basing an economy around Coal, Slaves, and War Industry. Does it seem practical?

Tags: warfare, economy, slavery, mining, industrial-age

So right now I've been tasked to come up with a world for a story that centers around what we could probably describe as post-civil war era. Coal is a resource needed for fueling machines and modes of industry, but it can only be mined with the use of slaves. The only way to get slaves however is through warfare as the offspring of slaves are conscripted into the army without ever knowing their parents, which brings up the heat and central plot of the story. Does this economy make sense and can it hold?

Comment: *"but it can only be mined with the use of slaves"* - are there any reasons for that?

Comment: The work is considered lowly, the conditions horrifying, the mining industry not wanting to pay people, and it's monopolized so no competition. Slaves are reserved for the wealthy as servants or used up until they die. Slaves do not exclusively work in coal, but its where the majority go--like the cotton fields of the south.

Comment: @FrancisMoon in the USA slaves were not used in the mines or railroads BECAUSE they were slaves.  People didn't want to risk having to buy another slave when you could just replace a worker for nothing.

Comment: Slaves were used in mining for non-precious ores, like coal and iron. I believe a company working on a mass scale could enforce the labor of potentially thousands in a single location. Free people can join the mining industry, but only as enforcers and collection runners.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Francis Moon! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Comment: FrancisMoon what you describe is mining in middle ages, for example. And even in places that had slaves, they mostly weren't used, for the reason @RichardU told. At least not coal and salt, expensive commodities crucial for economy. Even ancient Rome didn't send normal slaves to mine, and slaves it did sent were meant to die there, rather than to be effective miners... As for USA and iron, we basically don't know: (https://www.quora.com/Were-black-slaves-ever-used-in-the-US-in-mining) - slaves built infrastructure and *might* be used as miners - but no hard proof they were.

Comment: This could be a good story plot, and several good questions, but it's really broad right now with some of the structure not settled.  I'd be interested to see how this develops.

Comment: What are the conditions of the nation your describing and who are they attacking? Is this meant to be alt history?

Comment: It's like alt-history, but not quite. Anyways, the enemy is an undefined confederacy of tribes. Think of Iroquois. Anyways, this confederacy has banded together to stop the land grabbing conquest of this "Republic." The Republic has technology on it's hands, but lacks the manpower for an effective fighting force. The main reason for this war of indiscriminate killing and enslavement of the native populous is for the acquisition of land, resources, and to fill the shoes of a long since dead empire that they hope to resemble in this enormous vaccum they left behind.

Comment: Who raises "the offspring of slaves" for all those years until they can be conscripted? Are they paid? Are folks who ostensibly know the children's origin and fate...yet don't care enough to break the cycle...really the ones you want raising children who are fated to carry deadly weapons? And why should these perhaps emotionally crippled orphans have any loyalty to the army they have been conscripted into? The situation seems ripe for mutiny and desertion.

Comment: You cannot "base an economy upon war" since war is not a productive economic enterprise. War does not improve living standards or provide useful useful goods or services to trade. Often the onerous taxes and heavy debts by states at war do quite the opposite. Orwell in *1984* used endless war to deliberately suppress living standards (among other desirable effects) for political purposes.

Comment: Are you familiar with [S. M. Stirling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._M._Stirling)'s [*Draka*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Domination) series (*Marching Through Georgia*, *Under the Yoke*, *The Stone Dogs*, *Drakon*)? The Domination is an expanding empire based on slave labor and an army of Janissaries. (Bonus: they are really good fantasy / science-fiction / alternate history novels.)

Comment: Sounds like England/Wales during it's colonial phase, around the time of the American Revolution..

Answer (score 4):

This would be unsustainable, as you'd have slaves at every critical point of your economy.  With your coal mining slaves being deprived of their children, they would have literally nothing to lose by triggering massive explosions in the mines (Coal dust is EXTREMELY explosive). Which would cripple your economy, devastate your ability to make war, and end your source of conscription.

Morale in your army would be low as well, as they would have no family that they knew about back home.  Nobody to defend.  This would also tax loyalty.

This could work out only if there were a way to move up out of slavery and if the soldiers DID know their parents. (Fight to free mom and dad!).

As it is, I don't see this working for long.

Comment: Mining slaves essentially don't have children. The infants wouldn't survive the pollutants. I probably should have reformed my wording a bit. No, the children conscripted move out of slavery and join the ranks as soldiers to earn their freedom. They could purchase their parents, if they so choose, but you have to be free in order use currency or have any purchasing power.Keep in mind they are recruited at a young age so that they wouldn't have a longing to go home. Plus slave children are not the only ones in the army. They're just the conscript force to help fill in the ranks.

Comment: As I remember slaves have often been used as miners; one thing the South complained about before the Civil War was California becoming a free state in 1850, eliminating the potential market for slave miners there.  I have often shuddered at the thought of the economic devastation for the North if the South started large scale slave coal mining to power large scale manufacturing using slaves.  Many Islamic countries used massive armies of slaves and ex slaves successfully.

Comment: @M.A.Golding yes, but salt and gold does not go BOOOOM, coal does.

Comment: "Morale in your army would be low as well, as they would have no family that they knew about back home. Nobody to defend. This would also tax loyalty." No, it would encourage loyalty the army. You need to read about the Jannisaries. Also, one of the great realizations about the military which only became accepted in the last century or two is that soldiers don't fight for country or family: they fight for their buddies.